# jQuery: smooth animate font-size change on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I have a jQuery animation function set-up to change the font size of the `.header-wrap` text when the document scrolls beyond 50px. This works, I'm not so keen on the solution I've got though, it's not very smooth, ideally I'd like the font-size to change smoothly as you scroll down the page, instead of having to stop scrolling the re-initiate the animation etc. It's just a bit jagged. 
jsFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/cXxDW/

HTML:

```
<div class="content-wrap"></div>
<div class="header-wrap">hello
    <br/>hello
    <br/>hello
    <br/>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).scroll(function () {
    if (window.scrollY > 50) {
        $(".header-wrap").stop().animate({
            fontSize: '17px'
        });
    } else {
        $(".header-wrap").stop().animate({
            fontSize: '25px'
        });
    }
});
```

Any suggestions / better, smoother solutions to the one I've got are more than welcome and greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wont get a very smooth animation of `fontSize`. But if you only need compatibility with modern browsers you could animate `zoom` instead.

You would have to fix your margins and positioning since those will be animated as well.

Here is a [proof-of-concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cXxDW/1/).

Comment: cheers for the suggestions—close but not quite right, still doesn't animate on scroll, only animates when you stop scrolling